# XBee S1 read values from API mode

Tags: embedded, xbee

I have two XBees S1-one attached to a temperature sensor. This Xbee reads analog values, converts them into digital values thanks to the ADC and transmits them.
The other XBee - the receiver, is connected to a computer via a USB Explorer.
This XBee  works in API mode. The XBee connected to a computer receives the data send by the transmitter. I monitor the received values with the X-CTU software, version 6.2.0. Up until this point, everything works fine.

However, the problem that I encounter is that the data received on the computer is coded: there are bits corresponding to the address of the receiver, bits corresponding to the address of the sender, the data itself, acknowledgment bits,etc.  My question is **how can I extract only the data bits** without all th other information send by the transmitter?

I tried to read the values with a USB to TTL cable, connecting this cable to the **Tx**, **Rx**,**GND** and **5V**(there is a 5V input in the USB Explorer despite that the XBee works at 3.3V) of the receiver XBee and using the **screen** command in Linux. However, in this way I receive ASCII characters and I want to receive the binary code.
I want to put those values in a database in order to be able to treat them later.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You need to decode the API frames -- header byte, frame length, frame type, etc.  Read the documentation to learn the format, and write code to process the bytes you're receiving.  There are libraries out there for many languages, check http://examples.digi.com/quick-reference/ for a list of them.

Answer (score 1):

With a library like  [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XBee), you can use function to get the data from your Xbee in python ;) (if you use linux)

You just have to initialise the port (should be on /dev/tty...) and than catch the data with a loop which check if new data is coming.

If you need more help I can send you part of my code (doesn't have it near me, it's on my raspy)

I hope I've help you ;) 
Thana